# Ошибка при создании базы данных sql в проекте VS ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, mvc

Пытаюсь создать файл базы данных в проекте asp.net в папке App_Data, но все время выходит ошибка. Перегружал ПК, в VS зашел под именем администратора - не помогает. На ПК установлена VS 2013 Ultimate, MS SQL Server 2014.[image: Создание файла БД]
[image: Ошибка при создании файла БД]

Comment: Покажите содержимое web.config - студия должна дописывать туда connection string для подключения к базе.

Comment: Раздела <connectionStrings> там не было. Смотрел видео по подключению, там прописывают этот раздел вручную <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BookContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\Bookstore.mdf';Integrated Security=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings> и все работает. Я пытался, у меня все тоже самое...

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась! В настройках среды VS СЕРВИС-Параметры-Инструменты базы данных-Подключения данных, была прописана строка (LocalDB)\v11.0 .Заменил ее на строку, которая в названии доступных серверов (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB, теперь файлы базы данных создаются и отображаются в папке App_Data и конечно в обозревателе серверов.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по ошибке, у вас не создан экземпляр SQL Server LocalDB, к которому пытается подключиться студия.

Нужно создать его вручную:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe" с v11.0
```

Comment: Папка Microsoft SQL Server\110 содержит папки: KeyFile, License Terms, SDK, Shared. Но указанная вами папка Tools со всеми подпапками и файлом SqlLocalDB.exe есть в папке Microsoft SQL Server\120. Как создать вручную?

Comment: Просто используйте SqlLocalDB.exe из 120 - она тоже сработает.

Comment: Дико извиняюсь, но как ее использовать??? Я реально не знаю...

Comment: @МихаилВишневецкий открыть консоль (cmd), вбить в ней команду из ответа. нажать ввод :)

Comment: Создал свою БД через консоль. При выполнении команды C:\SqlLocalDB info выводятся три запущенных базы: MSSQLLocalDB, ProjectsV12 One (это моя созданная). В проекте VS на вкладке Обозреватель обьектов SQL Server появились  сервера, но по-прежнему та же ошибка при создании файла БД в папке App-Data....

Comment: @МихаилВишневецкий имя должно быть v11.0, скорее всего. создайте именно с таким именем